# Running Nightly Builds as XP Scheduled Task - Classpath Issue

Tags: junit, classpath, nightly-build

I'm running JUnit nightly builds on my computer as a scheduled task in Windows XP.  My application uses Jaxb, therefore some of the tests need to reference xsd schemas using the system classpath.  When the nightly build runs while I'm not on the computer, I get an error like this:

***java.lang.Exception: Unable to load schema mySchema.xsd from classpath***

However, when I run the build manually I get no such error.  The environment variable for the location of my schemas is a *System* variable, not a User variable, so I don't know what could be causing this error.  What could be cause of this error?

**EDIT:** Alternatives like Hudson is not what I'm asking for.  I'm asking for a solution for the technology described above (batch file running as a scheduled task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that your working directory is different from what you expect (rather than the classpath variable specifically).  It's not immediately obvious if you are running this scheduled task as a user or as a system task.  In either case, it's worth finding out exactly where the task is running.

That said, while I used to set up automatic builds using Windows XP scheduled tasks (exactly as you are doing now), we currently use [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/).  In the abstract, this isn't that much different from what you're doing (running a build regularly) but it [increases your flexibility](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html).  Around here, the most valuable ability of CruiseControl is to detect that changes were committed and to only run the build *then*.  We find out about broken builds, broken unit tests, etc., within 10 minutes of a commit now.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) or [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/).  Both are easy to setup and will take care of this type of problem for you with more reporting, control, and improved usability.  You'll spend less time investigating build problems.

Comment: haskell? really? do you mean "hudson"?

Answer (score 1):

[hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) is another continuous integration engine, that is very very simple to setup:

[Hudson offers the following features](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson):

- Easy installation: Just java -jar
  hudson.war, or deploy it in a servlet
  container. No additional install, no
  database.
- Easy configuration: Hudson can be
  configured entirely from its friendly
  web GUI with extensive on-the-fly
  error checks and inline help. There's
  no need to tweak XML manually
  anymore, although if you'd like to do
  so, you can do that, too.
- Change set support: Hudson can
  generate a list of changes made into
  the build from CVS/Subversion/Mercurial. This
  is also done in a fairly efficient
  fashion, to reduce the load of the
  repository.
- Permanent links: Hudson gives you
  clean readable URLs for most of its
  pages, including some permalinks link
  "latest build"/"latest successful
  build", so that they can be easily
  linked from elsewhere.
- RSS/E-mail/IM Integration: Monitor
  build results by RSS or e-mail to get
  real-time notifications on failures.
- After-the-fact tagging: Builds can be
  tagged long after builds are
  completed JUnit/TestNG test
  reporting: JUnit test reports can be
  tabulated, summarized, and displayed
  with history information, such as
  when it started breaking, etc.
  History trend is plotted into a
  graph.
- Distributed builds: Hudson can
  distribute build/test loads to
  multiple computers. This lets you get
  the most out of those idle
  workstations sitting beneath
  developers' desks. File
  fingerprinting: Hudson can keep track
  of which build produced which jars,
  and which build is using which
  version of jars, and so on. This
  works even for jars that are produced
  outside Hudson, and is ideal for
  projects to track dependency.
- Plugin Support: Hudson can be
  extended via 3rd party plugins. You
  can write plugins to make Hudson
  support tools/processes that your
  team uses.